# How to iterate over a JSONModel in a sapUI XML-View?

Tags: xml, sapui5

How can I build a XML-View in SapUI5 that iterates over all elements in a JSONModel?

So far I have a **Controller**:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.myApp.myController", {
        onInit: function () {
            //// set data model on view
            var oData = {
                title: "A cool title",
                values: [{name: "Text 1"}, {name: "Text 2"}, {name: "Text 3"}]
            };
            var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        }
    });
});
```

and a **View**:

```
<mvc:View
        controllerName="sap.ui.demo.myApp.myController"
        xmlns="sap.m"
>
    <Panel expandable="true" expanded="true" headerText="{/title}" width="100%">
        <content>
            <!-- how to iterate over {/values} ? -->
        </content>
    </Panel>

</mvc:View>
```

Comment: currently it is a bit confusing, your Controller creates a new JSON but you are asking for how to iterate? what is your goal you want to achieve? I think you have to get the ID of the Panel, then its model ... sap.ui.getCore("PanelID").getProperty("yourPathOfValues").. or much simpler ... this.getView.getModel() which also has a path -> getProperty("path")... then you have the json

Comment: You are right, I have the JSON. I want to iterate over the content of the JSON array stored in the property `values`. For each name I like to see a label in my XML-View

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [aggregation binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/97830de2d7314e93b5c1ee3878a17be9.html) to bind the content of the panel to your values array. You have to add an template control that will be cloned for each array item. Use relative binding paths within the template to access the properties of the particular array item.

```xml
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.myApp.myController"
    xmlns="sap.m"
>
    <Panel expandable="true" expanded="true" headerText="{/title}" width="100%" content="{/values}">
        <content>
            <!-- give the template control which will be cloned for each entry in your array -->
            <Label text="{name}"/>
        </content>
    </Panel>
</mvc:View>
```

I hope this gives you some help.

Comment: Great. I thought this works only for lists and tables, i.e. for the items-aggregation. Never thought of using that for other aggregations.

Comment: Aggregation Binding works for every control that has aggregation(s). You can have nested controls in aggregations as well.

Comment: How can I do that if I want to loop a multiple panels. not only one panel ?

Comment: The Label in my example could be a Panel with some content of its own. For each item in the array it would clone that panel with its content.

Answer (score 1):

Just to reiterate:
You can use aggregation binding on **all controls** that have aggregations.
One of the simplest ways to output array data as a repeated Text control is a VBox:

```
<VBox items="{MyModel>/MyArrayProp}">
  <items>
    <Text text="{MyModel>FieldWithinMyArrayProp}" />
  </items>
</VBox >
```